# In App Purchase - Works in Development, not in Production

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app that has in app purchase, and when testing it in production, I see the "your purchase was successful" message, but do not see the product delivered. The code to update the balance of "currency" within my app is not being called.

This however, has worked in development.

I have
-the product is cleared for sale
-all banking contracts are valid and live

Adding some code here (this is the finished transaction method that's called from the "updatedTransaction" delegate callback method:

```
-(void)finishedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"PURCHASE MANAGER - finishedTransaction:");

    // call finish transaction on the queue.

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

    // Old Deprecated
    // [self checkReceipt:transaction.transactionReceipt];

    [self checkReceipt:receiptData];


    // set purchasing flag

    purchasing = FALSE;
}
```

The checkReceipt method creates JSON payload and sends it to the verifyReceipt URL.

My question is: if transaction.transactionReceipt is deprecated, can I still use it? also, if the appStoreReceiptURL is from the bundle, how does it have the transaction data?

Comment: Post some of your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You do not validate against the sandbox if you are in production, aren't you? Refering to this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html you need to validate against `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` in test environments and against `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` in production.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think that might be the issue, is I didn't change the validation to shift to the buy.tunes.apple.com link